# Не могу завершить алгоритм извлечения координат из строки

Tags: c++

Есть задача, частью которой является извлечение координат вида (x,y) из строки, уточню что x и y могут быть числами с плавающей точкой. Способ нахождения самих координат и добавления в вектор сделал, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что после добавления точки в вектор, необходимо убрать часть строки с этой координатой чтобы найти следующую, проблема в том что у меня не получается определить кол-во символов которые необходимо удалить в методе erase, много чего перепробовал, но ни к чему рациональному так и не пришел. Прилагаю кусок кода

```
vector <point> points;
point pointn;
string pointstr;

cout << "Введите координаты точек в виде (x,y)" << endl;
cin >> pointstr;

int flag = 0;
while (pointstr.find("(") != string::npos && pointstr.find(",") != string::npos && pointstr.find(")") != string::npos)
{   
    int count = 0;
    pointn.x = stod(pointstr.substr(pointstr.find("(") + 1, pointstr.find(",") - 1));
    pointn.y = stod(pointstr.substr(pointstr.find(",") + 1, pointstr.find(")") - 1));
    points.push_back(pointn);
    pointstr.erase(pointstr.find("("), count);
}
```

Comment: point это структура состоящая из двух значений типа double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы знаете, что начинаются координаты точки с `(` и до `)` так, что вам не нужно считать сколько там символов.

   Вот пример:

   ```
   pointstr.erase(pointstr.find("("), pointstr.find(")") + 1);
   ```

   +1 потому что удаление идет без учета последнего символа.
2. Зачем удалять? Можно просто дальше производить поиск, т.к. в функции `find` есть второй аргумент, начало поиска.

   ```
   size_t find (char c, size_t pos = 0)
   ```

   И да вы производите поиск по одному символу, так что лучше использовать не двойные кавычки, а ординарные.

   ```
   //Позиция (
   size_t start = pointstr.find('(');
   //Позиция ,
   size_t comma = pointstr.find(',');
   //Позиция )
   size_t end = pointstr.find(')');
   //Переведем в си строку для использования atof
   const char* pointstr_ = pointstr.c_str();
   while (start != string::npos && comma != string::npos && end != string::npos)
   {
       pointn.x = atof(pointstr_ + start + 1);
       pointn.y = atof(pointstr_ + comma + 1);
       points.push_back(pointn);
       start = pointstr.find('(', end + 1);
       comma = pointstr.find(',', start);
       end = pointstr.find(')', comma);
   }
   ```

   [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) - это аналог функции `atod` только для си строк, и работает немного удобней чем `atod` т.к. не придется обрезать строку.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, в меня реально новая информация вошла